# Is there a name for the fixed-length sequence $[a_0, a_1, \cdots, a_k]$, where $a_i = \frac{2^i}{2^{k+1}-1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

I am wondering if there is a known name for the following sequence or if it belongs to a known family. It looks to me like there is one but I cannot remember.

It's a fixed-length sequence of the type:

$[a_0, a_1, \cdots, a_k]$ where $a_i = \frac{2^i}{2^{k+1}-1}$.

Example $[\frac{1}{7}, \frac{2}{7}, \frac{4}{7}]$.

It can be also be written as: $a_i = \frac{2^i}{\sum_{j=0}^k 2^j}$.

Comment: It is geometric with common ratio 2

Comment: That's too general I think. I thought there is a name like the Fibonacci sequence. Because it's a sequence which sums to 1 and each member is double the size of the previous. So it's a good sequence to use as weights in a weighted average of something where you care a lot more for the last samples. Something like an exponential moving average.

Comment: I am not sure why you think that nomenclature is too general. That is a precise description of that sequence, and the fact they sum to one is simply a normalization.  Other descriptions would depend on your context; if I was writing a paper and these are intended to be weights of a weighted average, then perhaps I might refer to them as "exponential weights," and from context, this will be clear to the reader.

Comment: I see. Then would you give it as an answer so I can accept it and close this question?

Comment: of course no prob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally, the sequence is geometric with common ratio 2.  But how you choose to describe it would depend on your context.  For instance, if I was writing a paper and these are intended to be weights of a weighted average, then perhaps I might refer to them simply as "exponential weights," and from context, this will be clear to the reader.